# How to store a single row data into a string array of sqlite database in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, sqlite

I have called a function `returnCurrentNameById()` by passing the `id` of the particular row. But it gives an error.

```
String[] s1;

public String[] returnCurrentNameById(int k) throws SQLException{  

    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ID1, KEY_NAME, Key_DOB, KEY_AGE, KEY_PHONE_NO, Key_EXPERIENCE, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_STATUS, KEY_STATUS};
    SQLiteDatabase db3 = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db3.query(DATA_BASE_TABLE_NAME1, columns, KEY_ID1 + "=" + k, null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        for(int i = 0; i<=8; i++){
            s1[i] = c.getString(i);
        }
        return s1;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The Log cat error report is:

```
02-15 16:38:13.424    1545-1545/world.com.my`enter code here`progect09 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-15 16:38:13.464    1545-1545/world.com.myprogect09 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2bc9a300)
02-15 16:38:13.533    1545-1545/world.com.myprogect09 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at world.com.myprogect09.DataBaseSQL.returnCurrentNameById1(DataBaseSQL.java:209)
            at world.com.myprogect09.ThirdActivity.isClicked(ThirdActivity.java:74)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-15 16:38:34.491    1545-1545/world.com.myprogect09 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1545 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What's the error it throws? Show your `logcat`

Comment: In the headline you state that a string shall be stored, but it seems that the code does only read the database. Could you please fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialized your `s1` array.

Use

```
s1 = new String[9];
```

to allocate an array of 9 elements.

Also check the return value of `moveToFirst()` so you don't get an exception in case the query returns no rows.

Comment: Thanks sir, the problem was the string s1[] which I was not initialized with new operator. Therefor, NullPointerException occurs

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 Cursor c = db3.query(DATA_BASE_TABLE_NAME1, columns, KEY_ID1 + "=" + k, null, null, null, null);
```

with

```
 Cursor c = db3.query(DATA_BASE_TABLE_NAME1, columns, KEY_ID1 + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(k)}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Sorry the problem still there, it gives AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Comment: "IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity" can caused due to lot of reasons. please post your log cat

Comment: Something in line 209 on DataBaseSQL.class is null. check what it is